# How to make the csv file from django.http.response.StreamingHttpResponse

Tags: python, django

I have `StreamingHttpResponse` and it downloads the csv file in brower.

Now I want to use this in testcase

```
response = self.client.get('/lusers/?&export=csv')
```

`response` is  `StreamingHttpResponse`

How can I make the `csv` file from this (not via browser)

and check the contents??

```
self.assertContains(response, "dataincsv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make text string from `StreamingHttpResponse` like this:

```py
str_response = '\n'.join(s.decode('U8') for s in response)
```

or

```py
str_response = '\n'.join(map(lambda s: s.decode('U8'), iter(response)))
```

and check content with:

```py
self.assertContains(str_response, "dataincsv")
```

`StreamingHttpResponse` is iterable object, and you can iteratate through this object any way you need.

For example if you want to write to file you could do something like:

```py
# ...
for line in response:
    some_file.write(line)
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Ah, `response` is iterable. however self.assertContains returns the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'status_code'`  it still try to find the `.status_code`

Comment: Depending on what `self.assertContains` actually do, you may need to impelemt different logic. If you convert `StreamingHttpResponse` to string then you can't check response code on that string. So I think you should impement two checks: one test is for `status_code` and another test is to check your csv file contains some text.